# What does the condition "email ~* 'link1.com$'" mean?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Let's say `table1` has a column named `email`.
Then the code is like:

```
select variable1, variable2
from table1
where email ~* 'link1.com$' and not email ~* 'link2.com$';
```

What is the meaning of "~*"?
Does it mean any data that in such regular expression format?

Answer (score 3):

Your specific RDBMS seems to be Postgres.  I can't find the `~*` operator in other documentation.

Anyway the [Postgres documentation for `~*`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) says

> Matches regular expression, case insensitive

Instead of `not email ~*` you could use `email !~*`, but I don't think that matters much.  You may not need regular expressions at all here and instead use `LIKE '%link1.com'`, etc.